# How to make reference style of New journal of physics by latex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have tried to use LaTeX to make the references like

> [18] Babu K S and Ma E 2008 Int. J. Mod. Phys. A 23 1813

for a long time, my attempts involved

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
```

but the output has colon  between author and year and comma in the references, e.g.

> Zoller, P.: 2001, Long-distance quantum communication with atomic ensembles and linear optics,Nat.414, 413

How to remove the colon and comma in the references?

Comment: I downloaded the LaTeX guidelines of the publisher of the New Journal of Physics (https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/). The file `IOPLaTeXGuidelines.pdf` says:  "For the numerical (Vancouver) reference style **we recommend that authors use `unsrt.bst`; this does not quite follow the style of published articles in our journals but this is not a problem.** ....

Comment: ... Alternatively `iopart-num.bst` created by Mark A Caprio produces a reference style that closely matches that in published articles. The file is available from
http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/iopart-num/." Later on it says "Please make sure that you include your `.bib` bibliographic database file(s) and any `.bst` style file(s) you have used." ...

Comment: ... The passage for author-year citation goes into a little more detail: "[If you use `dcu.bst`] The output differs a little from the final journal reference style, but all of the necessary information is present and the reference list will be formatted into journal house style as part of the production process if your article is accepted for publication." So just use `unsrt` and don't worry about the differences.

Comment: @moewe, I wonder what secret sauce they have that they don't just share their .bst with aspiring authors...

Comment: @vonbrand They may not actually have a `.bst` file. Depending on their workflow LaTeX or BibTeX may not be involved that much in producing the final output. In that case they may have their own systems that deal with and (re-)format the references.